# iphone is adding a weird left margin/padding

Tags: iphone, web, margin

This is [a website](http://kondor.co.il/?kondismob=1) with the mobile view.

The website width is 640px but the iPhone renders the document in 678px. In android it look great.

I added viewport meta:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=640, user-scalable">
```

And the body CSS is:

```
body,html{
margin:0px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
padding:0px;
font-size:14px;
font-family: "Arial";
background: white;
direction: rtl;
text-align: right;
width:640px !important;
overflow: hidden;}
```

In iPhone it looks like this:

[image]

As you can see it adds 38 pixels on the left side, not related to the body (if I set the body background to blue the side still stays white).

I tried everything but with no luck.
Any ideas?

Comment: Do you use [Normalize.css](http://necolas.github.com/normalize.css/) to reset every CSS rules at the first place ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution.

These lines were added because of the right alignment on the body CSS:

```
text-align:right;
direction:rtl;
```

If I remove these lines and add them to a div inside the body it's working fine.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly it would help to be starting with clean HTML and CSS—your HTML is far from valid, and that can cause all sorts of errors (see [here](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://kondor.co.il/?kondismob=1&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0) just for the HTML errors...).

Secondly:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=640, user-scalable">
```

is incorrect. It needs to be:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=640, user-scalable=yes">
```

and it would be better practice if it was:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=yes">
```

(See [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/appleapplications/reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/MetaTags.html)).

With a clean starting-point, it will be easier to debug. Also, turn on the Mobile Safari debug console and respond to any messages it gives you.

Comment: Hi 10x for your answer, First off all user-scalable is 0 when non value is written,
Second the website was coded to be 640px so width cannot be device-width because its layout
is not stretch nor responsive
So in another device i.e galaxy s1 when the resulotion is 320px ill see half of the website

Comment: Something such as `content="width=640"` where no `user-scalable` setting is included does indeed equate to `content="width=640, user-scalable=no"`. However, `<meta name="viewport" content="width=640, user-scalable">` triggers an error; include the `user-scalable` bit and you MUST set it to `yes` or `no`.